# xtext generator forward input to output

Tags: java, eclipse-emf, xtext, xtend, emf

How to forward the part of the parsed tree from input to output in xtend generator?

For instance, in some cases of output code generation, I do not need to parse the parameters of some constructor/functions. I only need to put this constants, variables names, expessions, etc. directly to the output code (forward all inside braces):

input DSL code:

```
CREATE_OBJECT_O(3, a, 5+6 )
```

output(may be some Java or C++ code):

```
Object o = new Object_Impl(3, a, 5+6 )
```

some part of xtext grammar:

```
ParameterList:
    (parameter+=Parameter ( "," parameter+=Parameter)* )?
    ;
Parameter:
    variableExpression=VariableExpression |(texts+=TextInParameter | macroSubstitutions+=MacroSubstitution)*;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different services for doing that in Xtext:

1. You can inject the org.eclipse.xtext.serializer.ISerializer service, and then call serializer.serialize(EObject) for outputting the object in a textual format. This uses serialization rules, however, if it does not work during editing (e.g. when using inside a JVMModelInferrer).
2. The class org.eclipse.xtext.nodemodel.util.NodeModelUtils that contains static methods useful here. These methods use the original textual format, keeping the original formatting, so it is usable during editing.

   ```
   val eObjectNode = NodeModelUtils::getNode(eObject)
   eObjectNode.text //this is the output

   // Or alternatively getTokenText returns the string without hidden tokens
   NodeModelUtils::getTokenText(NodeModelUtils::getNode(eObject))
   ```